# how to click two button at the same time by adb shell ？

Tags: android, adb

I want to tap the two buttons on the screen to pass their coordinates by adb at the same time。I only know click one at the same time，like this：

```
adb -s fe158b68 shell input tap 975 1412
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "buttons" - a physical button or a widget button?

Answer (score 2):

**Try to use something like this:**

```
adb shell "input keyevent 67 && input keyevent 67"
```

**To click on two different coordinates on the screen, Use this**

```
input tap x1 y1 && input tap x2 y2
```

where x1,y1 and x2,y2 are two different coordinates

Comment: Maybe I not describe the problem clearly.  actually, I want to click two coordinate on screen.

Comment: Updated. Pls have a look